# How to execute SSIS package from VB.NET Windows application?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to execute a SQL dtsx package from a Windows 2005 VB app?

If so, can someone show me how or send me a link?
I followed the instructions at:
http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-ms_sql-xAKCmQKI/  but the package result was failure. Could this be because the dtsx was not on the local machine? The package works aok by itself.

Comment: Addendum: I added an event listener and discovered that the specific error message is: "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW.  The product level is insufficient for component..."

The first 2 steps of the package are successful but it fails on the 3rd which is a data transformation.

General consensus is that the edition of SQL Server is at fault. Do you agree? How best to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW error code - see 
http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2006/11/11/ssis-product-level-is-insufficient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the file `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll` and add this resource into your Visual Studio project :

1. You might be able to find this file by going to `Project --> Add

   Reference... --> Browse` in Visual Studio, and searching for this
   file in your `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` directory.
2. If you can't find it there (which is what happened to me), go to the
   `Run...` prompt in Windows and enter `C:\Windows\assembly\gac_msil`.
   Then, in this folder's search box, enter the file name
   `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll`. Copy-paste this file into
   somewhere that is much easier to find, and add this reference into
   your Visual Studio project as mentioned above.

---

So, now that all of that crazy stuff is done, here's an idea of how to execute a `.dtsx` SSIS package in VB.NET. *This is untested, with the help of someone smarter than me, whom got the idea from someone else smarter* **;)** :

```
Protected Friend Sub loadSSISPackage(ByVal packageFile As String)

    If Me.fileExists(packageFile) AndAlso packageFile.EndsWith(".dtsx") Then
        Dim pkg As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package
        Dim app As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application
        Dim pkgResults As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult

        pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageFile, Nothing)
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute()
        MsgBox(pkgResults.ToString())
    Else
        Environment.Exit(-1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you also need to set a  reference (import Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts)

```
import Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts

Protected Friend Sub loadSSISPackage(ByVal packageFile As String)
    If Me.fileExists(packageFile) AndAlso packageFile.EndsWith(".dtsx") Then
        Dim pkg As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package
        Dim app As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application
        Dim pkgResults As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult

        pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageFile, Nothing)
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute()
        MsgBox(pkgResults.ToString())
    Else
        Environment.Exit(-1)
    End If
End Sub
```